# nscd dead but subsys locked

Tags: linux, pid

```
service nsd status
nscd dead but subsys locked
```

It starts fine but eventually crashes...

```
server:
logfile: "/var/log/nsd.log"
pidfile: "/var/run/nsd/nsd.pid"
```

What randomly causes NSD to do this?

Log:

```
[1354003784] nsd[403807]: notice: nsd started (NSD 3.2.13), pid 403807
[1354003804] nsd[403810]: info: NSTATS 1354003804 1354003784 A=33 TXT=1 AAAA=7
[1354003804] nsd[403810]: info: XSTATS 1354003804 1354003784 RR=0 RNXD=0 RFwdR=0 RDupR=0 RFail=0 RFErr=0 RErr=0 RAXFR=0 RLame=0 ROpts=0 SSysQ=0 SAns=41 SFwdQ=0 SDupQ=0 SErr=0 RQ=41 RIQ=0 RFwdQ=0 RDupQ=0 RTCP=0 SFwdR=0 SFail=2 SFErr=0 SNaAns=0 SNXD=2 RUQ=0 RURQ=0 RUXFR=0 RUUpd=0
[1354003888] nsd[404385]: error: ...stale pid file from process 403807
[1354003888] nsd[404386]: notice: nsd started (NSD 3.2.13), pid 404386
[1354004044] nsd[404389]: info: NSTATS 1354004044 1354003888 A=310 NS=1 MX=20 TXT=4 AAAA=83 TYPE255=1
[1354004044] nsd[404389]: info: XSTATS 1354004044 1354003888 RR=0 RNXD=0 RFwdR=0 RDupR=0 RFail=0 RFErr=0 RErr=0 RAXFR=0 RLame=0 ROpts=0 SSysQ=0 SAns=419 SFwdQ=0 SDupQ=0 SErr=0 RQ=419 RIQ=0 RFwdQ=0 RDupQ=0 RTCP=0 SFwdR=0 SFail=107 SFErr=0 SNaAns=0 SNXD=7 RUQ=0 RURQ=0 RUXFR=0 RUUpd=0
[1354004063] nsd[405235]: error: ...stale pid file from process 404386
[1354004063] nsd[405238]: notice: nsd started (NSD 3.2.13), pid 405238
[1354004284] nsd[405243]: info: NSTATS 1354004284 1354004063 A=359 NS=1 MX=21 TXT=4 AAAA=64
[1354004284] nsd[405243]: info: XSTATS 1354004284 1354004063 RR=0 RNXD=0 RFwdR=0 RDupR=0 RFail=0 RFErr=0 RErr=0 RAXFR=0 RLame=0 ROpts=0 SSysQ=0 SAns=449 SFwdQ=0 SDupQ=0 SErr=0 RQ=449 RIQ=0 RFwdQ=0 RDupQ=0 RTCP=0 SFwdR=0 SFail=59 SFErr=0 SNaAns=0 SNXD=11 RUQ=0 RURQ=0 RUXFR=0 RUUpd=0
[1354004365] nsd[406999]: error: ...stale pid file from process 405238
[1354004365] nsd[407000]: notice: nsd started (NSD 3.2.13), pid 407000
[1354004529] nsd[407005]: info: NSTATS 1354004529 1354004365 A=253 NS=2 CNAME=1 MX=65 TXT=3 AAAA=56 TYPE38=6 SPF=1 TYPE255=2
[1354004529] nsd[407005]: info: XSTATS 1354004529 1354004365 RR=0 RNXD=0 RFwdR=0 RDupR=0 RFail=0 RFErr=0 RErr=0 RAXFR=0 RLame=0 ROpts=0 SSysQ=0 SAns=389 SFwdQ=0 SDupQ=0 SErr=0 RQ=389 RIQ=0 RFwdQ=0 RDupQ=0 RTCP=0 SFwdR=0 SFail=82 SFErr=0 SNaAns=0 SNXD=7 RUQ=0 RURQ=0 RUXFR=0 RUUpd=0
[1354004665] nsd[412757]: error: ...stale pid file from process 407000
[1354004665] nsd[412758]: notice: nsd started (NSD 3.2.13), pid 412758
[1354004764] nsd[412767]: info: NSTATS 1354004764 1354004665 A=248 MX=14 TXT=3 AAAA=21
[1354004764] nsd[412767]: info: XSTATS 1354004764 1354004665 RR=0 RNXD=0 RFwdR=0 RDupR=0 RFail=0 RFErr=0 RErr=0 RAXFR=0 RLame=0 ROpts=0 SSysQ=0 SAns=286 SFwdQ=0 SDupQ=0 SErr=0 RQ=286 RIQ=0 RFwdQ=0 RDupQ=0 RTCP=0 SFwdR=0 SFail=43 SFErr=0 SNaAns=0 SNXD=4 RUQ=0 RURQ=0 RUXFR=0 RUUpd=0
[1354004860] nsd[413561]: error: ...stale pid file from process 412758
[1354004860] nsd[413562]: notice: nsd started (NSD 3.2.13), pid 413562
```

Comment: What operating system/version/distribution are you using?

Comment: centos 64bit/2.6.32

Comment: Look at your logs to see why it's crashing. The filtered output you provided shows nothing, probably _because_ you filtered out anything useful.

Comment: that was the log and that is about it

Comment: FYI I was getting this same error on centos 6 in docker environment. Turning on logfile and set debug-level to 10 in /etc/nscd.conf let me see the error "cannot stat() file `/etc/netgroup'", so I created that file and now "service nscd status" shows it running.

Answer (score 1):

2.6.32 is what's used in centos 6. On centos 6, nscd is no longer recommended. All authentication is done via SSSD, including caching. For hostname caching it's better to use something like dnsmasq.